# Delete last line in txt file

Tags: c#, datagridview

I wrote a foreach loop for my datagridview to write all rows to txt file.
I have a problem as it adds 2 empty lines at the end, as 1 row is full of empty cells after adding/reading to datagrid view.
Is there any way to omit the last line or delete it in txt?

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.DB.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewCell item2 in item.Cells)
    {   
        if(item2.Value != null)
        filewrite.Write(item2.Value.ToString() + " ");
    }
    filewrite.WriteLine("");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx) to make sure you only ever write out to the file if there is content in the cell e.g.

```
var cellValue = item2.Value.ToString();
if (!String.IsNullOrWhitespace(cellValue)) {
    filewrite.Write(cellValue + " ");
}
```

You can actually do this pretty easily using LINQ

```
var rows = this.DB.Rows.Select(r => String.Join(" ", r.Cells.Select(c => c.Value)))
                       .Where(x => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace((string)x));

File.WriteAllLines("database.txt", rows);
```

Comment: Won't work like this. item2.Value isn't string, and item2.Value.ToString() doesn't work neither

Comment: @user3658127 i guess it does not work cause you execute the `filewrite.WriteLine("");` line anyway.

Comment: @user3658127 updated for the `ToString`. If you are saying that check doesn't work then it's clearly because `item2.Value` *contains* something. If you mean you still end up with an empty line at the end...yes you will because you have `filewrite.WriteLine("")` after the loop. Your question was "*how can you stop **2** empty lines*" - this code would prevent the empty row being output but it won't prevent the empty line at the end because you appear to be doing that deliberately.

Comment: I handled 1 empty line properly in my reading method, needed to delete the second one, solved it already :) and my question didn't involve second last line, I used it on demand

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this like below:

```
for(int i = 0; i< this.DB.Rows.Count-1; i++)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewCell item2 in item.Cells)
    {   
        if(item2.Value != null)
            filewrite.Write(item2.Value.ToString() + " ");
    }

    filewrite.WriteLine("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you may have other empty rows in your data.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.DB.Rows)
{
    var printRow = false;
    foreach (DataGridViewCell item2 in item.Cells)
    {   
        if(!String.IsNullOrWhitespace(item2.Value.ToString()))
        {
            printRow = true;
            filewrite.Write(item2.Value.ToString() + " ");
        }
    }
    if (printRow)
    {
        filewrite.WriteLine("");
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't know why it still says that item2.Value is invalid argument

Answer (score 0):

```
private void tofile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string file = "database.txt";
    StreamWriter filewrite;
    filewrite = new StreamWriter(file);
    int rcount = DB.Rows.Count;

    for(int i = 0; i < this.DB.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewCell item2 in this.DB.Rows[i].Cells)
        {   
            if(item2.Value != null)
                filewrite.Write(item2.Value.ToString() + " ");
        }

        filewrite.WriteLine("");
    }

    filewrite.Close();
}
```

SOLVED :)